# Userform ComboBox enabling textboxes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a userform with a combobox and multiple textboxes. I used the BeforeUpdate event for the combobox to determine which boxes in the field were enabled at a given time. The problem I have is, everytime I change the combobox the boxes aren't enabled or disabled until I click on one of them. Is it possible to refresh all of the boxes after the combobox selection is made? I've included a sample of the code I'm using; there are 27 textboxes that are enabled or disabled depending on 6 different combobox options.Thanks!

```
Private Sub AdminCombo_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If AdminCombo = "Composite" Then
        AdminCompCurr.Enabled = True
        AdminCompRenNum.Enabled = True
        AdminCompRenPer.Enabled = True
        AdminEEOnlyCurr.Enabled = False
        AdminEEOnlyRenNum.Enabled = False
        AdminEEOnlyRenPer.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you use the `AdminCombo_AfterUpdate` event instead?

Comment: Thanks! It actually didn't help it, but I tried AdminCombo_Change() event and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have the answer here for future use.

Change the line:

```
Private Sub AdminCombo_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
```

to

```
Private Sub AdminCombo_Change(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
```

This uses the event after the combobox is changed to update the needed textboxes.